# Facebook Feed not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 2 Facebook feeds (facebook.com/deaconesshealthsystem and facebook.com/deaconesswomenshospital) that I'm trying to display at http://www.deaconess.com (Bottom of the page > Social Tab). The strange thing is that the Women's Hospital feeds works fine. But the Health System feed always Fails to load in IE. Even if I remove the Women's Hospital feed, the Health System feed fails. It works for me in Chrome most of the time. But occasionally it even fails in Chrome. It never shows in IE.

There is a javascript error that occurs on facebooks page.php. The error displayed is:

```
Unable to get property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference
```

It appears that the div facebook creates inside the iframe with an id "u_0_0" is not being created for some reason. Thus throwing the above error when the script attempts to get the offsetWidth of this div element.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a legit bug. I would recommend you file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs, and remember to provide as much information as possible in order for this to be fixed as soon as possible!

Comment: I can't file bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs. They require a valid facebook app id to submit a bug. This is a javascript sdk issue in the dialog feed. it's not in a facebook app. Also when I run my code in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/javascript-console/?from_bug_tool it works fine. So There has to be something else causing it.